# Output of command on host into in ARG in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I need the output of a command run on the host to be used further in a Dockerfile.

Something like this:

```
ARG version
version = `cat version.txt` <--- this has to be run on the host
RUN sed -i "s/VER*/$version/g" /file/in/container
```

Is it clear what I mean? :)
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using this command:

```
docker build --build-arg version=$(cat version.txt) .
```

The Dockerfile (Update: I have removed `ENV` and used the value of `ARG` directly)

```
ARG version
RUN sed -i "s/VER*/${version}/g" /file/in/container
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! This will result in a monster of a command line. Is there no way of doing the cat in the Dockerfile?

Comment: No as all the commands inside the dockerfile meant to be executed inside the container itself during the image preparation. note that I have updated the Dockerfile and removed the need to have `ENV` there

Comment: @mircealungu is anything else that needs to be explained to answer your question ?